# selecting SUM from large table efficiency

Tags: mysql, performance, sum, range

Table structure:

db_table

id (int), type (string), value(decimal), filter(json encoded string),time(int)

Where type represents the type of metric that is being stored and filter represents any keys that is relevant to filtering by or sorting.

Say I want to know the order sales of customer 100 between two dates. My table might look like this:

1 , order , 100.00 , {"user":100}, 1464782400

2 , order , 500.00 , {"user":100}, 1464782700

3 , order , 200.00 , {"user":200}, 1464782100

4 , order , 600.00 , {"user":100}, 1464782200

5 , order , 400.00 , {"user":200}, 1464782900

This is one of many queries i've tried which is too slow for my application ( the table has over a million rows ):

```
SELECT SUM(`value`) FROM `db_table` WHERE `time` BETWEEN 1464782100 AND 1464782900 AND `type` = 'order' AND `filter` LIKE '"user":200'
```

This isn't cutting it, is there any way to improve the efficiency of the query? I'm at about .5 seconds per query at best and need to be far faster than that.

Answer (score 0):

```
INDEX(type, filter, time),
INDEX(type, time)
```

You say `filter LIKE...`; Would a simple `filter =...` work?  Or will you sometimes be using wildcards?  The first index is good if you don't need wildcards; the second is better if you have wildcards

But the real solution is to avoid running the query.  Your query smells like a Data Warehouse application and you are producing a 'report'.  To make that more efficient, build and maintain a [*Summary table*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/data-warehousing-summary-tables/) that has subtotals for each combination of `type`, `filter`, and, say, day.  Then run the query against the summary table, summing up the subtotals.